# NodeMCU (ESP8266) Defining static IP, stops Firebase processing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Hello i am new to NodeMCU (ESP8266) i am building a small program to connect with WIFI (with internet) and if internet is not available i want to process request over IP address.

I am using firebase as a database / server to fetch the status. And process command through a URL like http://192.168.1.223/on?pin=04 if internet is connected then no problem i can update firebase entry, but with same network (LAN) connection over wifi i want to process i need to have static IP. But the concern is i am not able to make this IP address static, and if i make it static then my NodeMCU is not able to connect with firebase.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "pushst-56f2c.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "mhBpzrNyhhwEGwmFxkVFTIEylwrXMw0gm"
#define PATH "/clients/devicename/watermotor"

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 223);  //Node static IP
IPAddress dns(192, 168, 1, 223);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

char ssid[] = "MyNetwork";   
char password[] = "Qwert98!!"; 

int wifiStatus = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() { 
      Serial.begin(115200); 

      delay(100);
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Your are connecting to;");
      Serial.println(ssid);

      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      WiFi.config(ip, dns, gateway, subnet);


      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        digitalWrite(WIFI_CONNECT_LED, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }

      wifiStatus = WiFi.status();

      if(wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED){
          digitalWrite(WIFI_CONNECT_LED, LOW);

         Serial.println("Your IP address is: ");
         Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  

         Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
         Firebase.set("/clients/devicename/watermotor/name", "Motor");
         Firebase.set("/clients/devicename/watermotor/relay_status", "off");
         Firebase.set("/clients/devicename/watermotor/device_status", "online");
         Firebase.stream(PATH);

         server.on("/on", handleOnRequest); //Associate the handler function
         server.on("/off", handleOffRequest); //Associate the handler function

         server.begin(); //Start the server
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("WiFi not connected");
      }

}


void loop() { 
    server.handleClient();
    if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.println("streaming error");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());
      delay(1000);
      return;
    }

    if (Firebase.available()) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Firebase available");
        Serial.println();
        FirebaseObject event = Firebase.readEvent();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if its there is some problem with FirebaseLibrary or its just the ESP8266!

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: is FIREBASE_AUTH your supersecret token? It's not so secret anymore

Comment: Yes it works fine if i dont put Static IP.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong DNS server IP address. In your sketch it is the same as the static IP address you assign to esp. Then the name of the firebase host can't be resolved by DNS.

The DNS server is usually the router/gateway.

```
IPAddress dns(192,168,1,1)
```